# Yii, error render widget form in forn

Tags: yii

I made a widget

```
<?php
class CSend extends CWidget
{
    public $model;
    public function init()
    {
        $this->model = new ContactForm();
    }
    public function run()
    {
        $this->render('send', array('model' => $this->model));
    }
}
```

view send

```
<div class="modal-backdrope"></div>
<div class="modal">
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'contact-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        'validateOnChange' => true,
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'ask_popup', 'name' => 'email-form'),
)); ?>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <h1>Povratne informacije</h1>
    <div class="modal-close"></div>

<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'name', array('class' => 'w-input inpt', 'placeholder' => 'Vaše ime')); ?>

<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'email', array('class' => 'w-input inpt', 'placeholder' => 'Vaša email adresa')); ?>

<?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'body', array('class' => 'w-input inpt', 'placeholder' => 'Vaša pitanja', 'cols' => 75, 'rows' => 5)); ?>

    <div class="w-clearfix captcha">
        <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('buttonLabel' => '', 'clickableImage' => true,
            'imageOptions' => array('title' =>  'Klikni na sliku za promjenu znaka'),))?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode', array('class' => 'w-input captcha-inpt')); ?>
    </div>

<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Pošaljite',array('site/send'),
    array(
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'type'=>'post',
        'success'=>'function(data) {
                                    if(data.status=="success")
                                    {
                                        $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
                                        $(".ask_popup").hide();
                                        $(".modal").prepend("<h3>Vaša poruka je poslana</h3>")
                                        setInterval(function(){
                                        $(".modal").find("h3").remove();
                                        $("#contact-form input[type=text], textarea").css("border-bottom", "solid #CCC 1px");
                                        $(".ask_popup").fadeOut();
                                        $(".modal-backdrope").fadeOut();
                                            }, 2000)
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $("#contact-form input[type=text], textarea").css("border-bottom", "solid #CCC 1px");
                                        console.log(data);
                                        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                            console.log(key);
                                            $("#contact-form #"+key).css("border-bottom", "solid red 2px");
                                            });
                                    }
                                }',),
    array('class' => 'w-button submit'));?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and call this widget in the layout

```
    </div>
    <?php $this->widget('CSend'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, an error, firefox: Saw a “form” start tag, but there was already an active “form” element. Nested forms are not allowed. Ignoring the tag.
How to do that was wrong? Sorry for my english.
=update=
I thought of another one about a widget, if it is to comment out everything is OK, where it contains a mistake?

```
<div class="gray">
    <?php $url = $this->getController()->createUrl('site/sc'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm($url, 'get'); ?>
    Security Code:
    <?php echo CHtml::textField('sc', '', array('size' => 40, 'id' => 'sc')); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Get receipt', array('id' => 'send'))?>
    <?php CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to close form tag by [$this->endWidget()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#endWidget-detail)

Comment: Could you also please specify where you get this error. W3C validator?

Comment: have found a bug, it is another widget, updated the question

Comment: `<?php CHtml::endForm(); ?>` i am a loser `<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>`
Missed 'echo' tag before end of widget :< thank you guys alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add in the bottom of the view of CSendWidget this code:

> ```
> <?php $form->endWidget(); ?>
> ```

You start widget `CActiveForm` by `beginWidget` and you must end  rendering this widget by `endWidget`

**Updated:**

I think you try to created form inside the other form be your updated answer (it's not allowed in HTML). You need it create outside or add it's fields in one form!

Comment: I have a widget there closed

Comment: Check you rendered html code and search </form>. If it more than 1 then try to investigate where is output this items and you can find this part of code...

Answer (score 0):

That error is thrown when you open a form tag in html, but do not close it properly and open another form tag, thus actually nesting forms, which is not allowed.

So before you call the widget using `<?php $this->widget('CSend'); ?>` make sure you've closed **all** form tags with either `</form>` if it's a normal html form or `<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>` if it's a CActiveForm.

EDIT: This must be done **BEFORE** you call your widget, as I suspect that another form is still open earlier on your page.

Also, don't forget to close your form tag/end your CActiveForm widget in your CSend widget like so:

View send:

```
<div class="modal-backdrope"></div>
    <div class="modal">
        <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'contact-form',
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                'validateOnChange' => true,
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'ask_popup', 'name' => 'email-form'),
        )); ?>
        <div class="result"></div>
        <h1>Povratne informacije</h1>
        <div class="modal-close"></div>

        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'name', array('class' => 'w-input inpt', 'placeholder' => 'Vaše ime')); ?>
        ....
        <?php $form->endWidget(); ?> // close form/CActiveForm widget here
        ....
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: My form in the widget is closed <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

Comment: Yes, but do you have **another** form somewhere **before** you call your widget? I think you have forgotten to close a different form/widget, earlier in your page.